# Best / easiest way to remove old electrical connectors?

Tags: electrical, removal, remodeling, gutters

I am planning to install gutters on my home. This means I need to remove the old and defunct 1950s style power pegs from my house (see photo).

I am thinking sawzall but it might not be the cleanest or flushest cut. Can they be unscrewed with a wrench if turned counter clockwise? What's the easiest way to remove them as cleanly as possible?

Thanks!

[image: Old pegs to remove]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a pry bar through the eye of the anchor. You are correct, rotating top left will bring them out. Alternatively, an adjustable wrench over both sides of the eye works very well. Turn it right out, don't cut it off, because it's much easier to caulk shut a hole or put new flashing over it if there's no stub sticking out. There are some eye bolts that go through the wood and have a nut on the inside. In those cases, you can remove some soffit and put a wrench on the nut inside. Don't get hit on the head when it comes out, and don't stand on the top step of a ladder.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out later today and report back / accept answer as-appropriate.

Comment: ... and don't make contact with your service drop with you or your tools. +1

Answer (score 2):

I accepted Kendall's answer, but wanted to explain how I solved this as while he had the right idea, it didn't work for my specific case.

As Kendall expected, I could pry bar the eyelets to turn them. However, they seemed to only turn about 90 degrees in either direction at which point they locked in place. I then tried to remove soffits to gain access from below however under these PVC soffits are original wood soffits. So I had no reasonably easy access to the two eyelets.

So, I got out the sawzall and using a bimetal blade I chopped the bolts off as flush to the flashing as I could. Then I moved the coax connection anchor down to above the window and caulked all the holes. Good to go!

Here's how it turned out just before I caulked it:

[image: done but not caulked]